# Nesting resource controllers with additional URL params in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to create routes for nested resource controllers in Laravel 5 like..

```
/customers/{customer}/modulename/clients/{client}
```

In the application I'm developing I have customers who are logging in to the application, but also sys-admins. Every customer can select multiple modules to use and within those modules there are sometimes the same models, but they're using different controllers.

I have used the following solutions, but they have some problems.

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
Route::resource('customers.clients', 'CustomerController');
```

I can't go for different modules in this solution, so I tried to make groups...

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customers/{customer}', ''], function(){
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'module1', ''], function(){
    Route::resource('clients', 'Module1\ClientAController');
  });
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'module2', ''], function(){
    Route::resource('clients', 'Module2\ClientBController');
  });
});
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

But the routes are getting annoying. When building the menu hierarchy this following route is quite difficult to create.

```
route('customers.{customer}.module1.clients.index');
```

Is what it should be, but I would like to get to go to...

```
route('customers.module1.clients.index');
```

Is there an option for the `Route::group()` function I'm missing or can I make a group within a route resource? Or should I just write out all the different `Route::get` and `Route::post` functions with the the `$options = ['uses' => '...', 'as' => 'customers.module1.clients.*']`

Comment: Why don't you use `Route::resource('customer.module.client');`?

Comment: I have thought of that solution, but I would like to use different Controllers for the different clients

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the following two routes:

```
Route::resource('customer','CustomerController');
Route::resource('customer.module.client','ClientController');
```

Then your routes would be like so:
[image]